# Why the value changed at each runtime in java using getbytes()..?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encode

I just want to clarify something using of `getbytes()` in `java`, i am doing simple program in Java **to encode the string using of getbytes()**,
but each run time the value should be change.. can anyone explain why its changing..?

**Here my sample code :**

```
  String m_a="Hello";

  byte[] b1 = m_a.getBytes();
```

**output 1 :**

```
            encoded value : [B@ffb35e
```

**output 2 :**

```
           encoded value : [B@fe0ce1
```

**output 3 :**

```
           encoded value : [B@ed3bff
```

How can i get the unique value of that string.

Comment: You don't print the content of you array. You print the memory address of it, which can change. Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b1));`

Comment: byte[] is an Object in Java. Hence, printing the byte[] will print the Object. Sadly, it doesn't know that you want the 'contents of the byte array'. Instead, it prints the memory address of the byte[].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're printing out the identifier for the object, not its content. if you print the actual bytes inside the array it should be the same every time

Comment: suppose i need to compare the two byte array is this correct way. Arrays.equals(b1, b2)